# Where to keep the data in a multi language android app and how access it

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I`m having trouble figuring out how to keep data for multi language application a quiz application.
I know that i have to keep them in *values/ or values-fr/* folder in order for android to access them for each language.
But where do I keep the questions in each language, there will be to many to access by:

```
<string name="Question 1">Bla Bla</string>
<string name="answer1">answer1</string>
<string name="answer2">answer2</string>
<string name="Question 2">Bla Bla</string>
<string name="answer1">answer1</string>
<string name="answer2">answer2</string>
```

I want to keep them something like this

```
<id>1<id>
<question>Question1</question>
<answer1>Answer 1</answer1>
<answer2>Answer 2</answer2>
<id>2<id>
<question>Question 2</question>
<answer1>Answer 1</answer1>
<answer2>Answer 2</answer2>
<id>3<id>
<question>Question 3</question>
<answer1>Answer 1</answer1>
<answer2>Answer 2</answer2>
```

And how to I get them from the file.

Comment: Try to use assets folder or database for more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You may just make the stable content multi language,such as the the label of `TextView` or the hint of `EditText`,but if you want to make the dynamic content multi language, I think it will mean a lot work to you.All the question should transfer to a lot of language.So I suggest you make your app multi version base on language.

Comment: Thank you. I will use a database to store multi language data. And strings.xml  to store the stable content.